# When does a FCM token expire?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When do FCM tokens expire? Is it at 6 months?

Answer (score 125):

It doesn't expire though. It renews itself if one of the following happens.

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client:

1. -The app deletes Instance ID
2. -The app is restored on a new device
3. -The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
4. -The user clears app data.

> **Monitor token generation**
>
> The onTokenRefreshcallback fires whenever a new token is generated, so
>   calling getToken in its context ensures that you are accessing a
>   current, available registration token. Make sure you have added the
>   service to your manifest, then call getToken in the context of
>   onTokenRefresh, and log the value as shown:

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

**EDIT**

[onTokenRefresh()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService#onTokenRefresh()) is now deprecated. [onNewToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService#onNewToken(java.lang.String)) should be used instead.

Comment: How can the server know if the new token is for a new device or just sent again to replace an old token?

Comment: Compare with device id or userID if you have those fields in serverside, and update accordingly

Comment: This is very interesting and makes sense considering the token generation strategy, can we get the source, please?

Comment: @cutiko I think this is the [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register). However I am having difficulties understanding this answer. In the documentation it is written that the token changes in those cases but it doesn't explain what happens with the original token!

Comment: @NoahMartin is not valid anymore if you store it in some place and then try to use it as the destination for any new FCM it won't work

Comment: Link to this answer's source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register

Answer (score 4):

Using firebase admin, you can do this:

```js
async function isValidDeviceToken (deviceToken) {
  const {
    results: [notifResult]
  } = await firebaseAdmin.messaging().sendToDevice(
    deviceToken,
    {
      notification: {
        title: 'Device Registration',
        message: 'Your device has been registered.'
      }
    },
    {
      dryRun: true
    }
  );

  // returns true if valid, false if not.
  return !notifResult.error;
}
```

what it does is it will check if the provided `deviceToken` is valid, behid the scene, firebase admin checks if the `deviceToken` is registered. If it is not registered, it will return the following error:

```
{
  error: FirebaseMessagingError: The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See the error documentation for more details. Remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.
      at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/aprilmintacpineda/projects/my-app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
      at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/aprilmintacpineda/projects/my-app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
      at new FirebaseMessagingError (/Users/aprilmintacpineda/projects/my-app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:256:16)
      at Function.FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (/Users/aprilmintacpineda/projects/my-app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:289:16)
      at /Users/aprilmintacpineda/projects/my-app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:105:63
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at mapRawResponseToDevicesResponse (/Users/aprilmintacpineda/projects/my-app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:101:26)
      at /Users/aprilmintacpineda/projects/my-app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:370:24
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
      at async isValidDeviceToken (/Users/aprilmintacpineda/projects/my-app/test.js:13:7) {
    errorInfo: {
      code: 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered',
      message: 'The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See the error documentation for more details. Remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.'
    },
    codePrefix: 'messaging'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) the token doesn't expire it only changes on certain events. Whenever a new token is generated a method onTokenRefereshId is called.To implement this create a class which extends FirebaseInstanceIdService and override the onRefreshToken as follows:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

Also do not forget to register this service in the manifests

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: This intent action is now called `com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT`, see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148336/what-to-do-with-the-instance-id-event-action-with-firebase-17-0-1

Answer (score 0):

If the app is not used for more than 1 to 2 months it becomes at status STALE, so the subscription and ability to refresh token stop. Its not a fixed time, but based on firebase documentation it suggest to check invalid token responses from the FCM backend or max registered time 2 month old.
Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens