# How to set up user class to handle FCM tokens for storage in Real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am attempting to develop the below data structure in a Firebase database with my user object in order to store FCM tokens in my database and I am not sure of how to implement my array list of fcm tokens in the User object

What is the best method to handle the FCM tokens for storage and retrieval?

[image: Structure]

```
public class User {
    private String uId;
    private String name;
    private String email;

      public ArrayList<Boolean> fcmTokens = new ArrayList<>();
    public User(String uId, String name, String email) {
        this.uId = uId;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;

    }
    public User() {

    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uId;
    }

    public void setUid(String uId) {
        this.uId = uId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

 public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
       this.email = email;
    }

///// HOW TO IMPLEMENT ARRAYLIST
```

Answer (score 0):

The registration tokens are something that changes [during these scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982619/when-does-a-fcm-token-expire) . I don't see any use of storing the reason to store historical tokens. Also, another issue might be downloading all the tokens every time when you want to download user1uid. So, I would suggest something like this.

```
--users
  -user1uid
     -name
     -email
     -fcmtokens
        -user1token:valueofuser1Token
```

And update the token everytime a user visits your app by calling updateRegistrationToken in your home page by passing the registrationToken.

```
  func updateRegistrationToken(registrationToken: String) {
    let userTokenRef = ref.child("users").child(user1uid)
    userTokenRef.setValue(["token": registrationToken])
}
```