# How long does the Firebase Cloud Messaging notification token expire?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to figure out the expiration date for the Firebase Cloud Messaging notification token.

```
  /// Returns the default FCM token for this device.
  ///
  /// On web, a [vapidKey] is required.
  Future<String?> getToken({
    String? vapidKey,
  }) {
    return _delegate.getToken(
      vapidKey: vapidKey,
    );
  }
```

I am using this token in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase, the Push service has no expiration time.

Only in some situations does the token cease to be valid:

- when the application is reinstalled;
- after cleaning the application cache;

More details are available at this link:

[When does a FCM token expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982619/when-does-a-fcm-token-expire)